# Can you normal hand wash (or machine wash) a polyester jacket that has mentioned dry clean only with a typical detergent?

Tags: clothing, laundry

I got a quilted bomber jacket from Amazon. It was mentioned "Care Instructions: Machine Wash" on product page. But later I found out a label inside jacket which says "**(P) Dry Clean Only**". *(So I assume Machine Wash specification was incorrect. Amazon customer care also said so).*

It's not a reputed branded or very good quality. It's a cheap and 'okay' jacket. Here are main specifications and photo:

[image]

[image]

So it's basically polyester. We don't have good dry cleaners nearby. They can't be trusted as it's a small town. Not even sure if they would follow dry clean guidelines.

On a separate note, it's a cheap budget jacket. IMO definitely not targeted to customers who can afford better branded / quality clothes. So it makes me wonder a little why no machine wash option is given because in my country, machine wash is more common and affordable. If I went for dry cleaning anyway, within 3-4 dry cleaning services, I would pay the total amount it actually costed to buy this jacket.

**Interestingly**, my mom actually washed it (gentle hand wash with mild detergent) because I tend to wash new bought clothes. I realized it later only that it has mentioned Dry Clean Only. I personally don't think it changed anything with jacket after wash. Maybe tiny bit more wrinkles. But I'm not sure how repeated washes (say 5-6 washes in winter seasons) would affect it.

**Would it be okay to gently wash such a jacket - like hand wash or machine wash with some gentle detergent? Or are there any other way to wash it so I don't need to worry about dry clean?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has been washed it can obviously be washed, as long as you keep being that careful every time.

I have noticed that companies selling clothing are very conservative in their care instructions. And I have ignored part of those instructions and had the items survive, but I was aware I was taking a risk.

So I say consider the value of the jacket, the cost of dry-cleaning, the bother to get it dry-cleaned and take a decision. Mine would be to wash, yours may still be to dry-clean.

Comment: Since we have only couple of small dry cleaners here (and I don't even trust them), I had made decision to buy one of same brand and plan to wash only. Hand wash with mild detergent. It's not expensive so even if it lasts a few more seasons, it would be worth it.